# Why structs took more space than it needs?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I saw that when I checked the size of struct it took 36 bytes, but the same variables (without the struct) took 33 bytes.
Why?

Comment: Probably some padding taking place. Post  an example

Comment: Can you show examples of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sizeof(struct) >= sum of all the structure members.
```

Because there might be extra padding for alignment requirements.That is the reason you are seeing that the size of the struct is more than what you thought.

Comment: There can also be padding in the middle of a structure.